# Does HR google your email address or username?

Tags: resume

How common is it for HR or recruiters to google your email or handle name address to find out more about you?

Comment: I have no empirical evidence to support this, but I surmise it's virtually a universal practice. IMO it would be negligent for someone in a hiring position not to do so.

Comment: Many places will explicitly ask for your facebook/ linkedin/ website details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more and more common for recruiters, HR people, and/or hiring managers to research a candidate on the Internet. This can be by simply looking at their LinkedIn page, Twitter, github, blog, and/or any other obviously related discoverable items, or by Googling them.

Of course, with Googling there's often the risk I'm going to find a bunch of other people with the same name even within the same area, so I generally don't press too hard down that path unless I know they do a lot of conference presenting or the like. Googling email addresses - most people are smart enough not to put those anywhere on the public Web and mainly it gets old Usenet news posts. I personally also don't bother with peoples' personal stuff like Facebook, but that would vary per job (as an engineering manager I could care less, and would probably prefer to not know, about everyone's non-work activities... I remember a contractor who told us his email was "bearnaked@aol.com", causing visions that were hard to unsee).

Comment: "idiot@aol.com"! People still do that? For a technical role I'd rate that as a strong negative, it suggests they are not familiar with the internet. Actually, for any role using the net in any way. If they're using a dumb name at AOL can they even use google?

Answer (score 3):

Treat it as a 100% certainty.  If I get your CV on my desk, I will Google you either before or after the interview.

That said, in most parts of the world, it would be illegal to refuse to hire you due to some of the stuff that I found.

Let's say you've tweeted "OMG! I'm pregnant :-)" or "Off to the Mosque for prayers" or "my artificial leg is broken :-(" etc - those aren't valid reasons not to hire someone.

If, however, I've found you spouting racist nonsense, or saying "hungover - gonna call in 'sick' #ScrewYouBoss" or similar - yeah, you're probably not getting the job!

So, what about the middle-ground?  If you support the "wrong" football team, that may rub some hiring managers up the wrong way.  But would you really want to work for someone that petty?

On the positive side - if I find your blog and it's full of helpful advice, or I find you've answered some really tough questions on StackExchange - that will definitely work in your favour.

Oh, and if your email address is SexyBlonde69@example.com - it's time for you to ditch the handle you thought was cool when you were 16 and get a new email address.  I hear Google gives them out for free :-)

Comment: While it's true, legally speaking, that you can't disqualify someone for finding "off to the mosque for prayers" on their Facebook profile, unless you write down that that is your reason how would they ever know?